# How to run Progress Bar before second form load in c# .net Windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a two forms in a .net windows application, I want to set a progress bar before second page load, because my second page is loading after 10 to 15 seconds, So,I want to run progress bar until second page load completed.

How could that possible?

Comment: You should post what you have tried and tell us where you're stuck. That gives us more detail, and we can quickly give an answer by copy-pasting the code with minor modifications. Questions like I-need-this,-give-me-code doesnt work in SO. 

Do a search on SO like "progress bar + backgroundworker". You will get enough questions on it anyway.. In the current format the question will be closed. You may read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before asking a question

Comment: See [A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

This can be good for you.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;

            int d;

            for (d = 0; d <= 100; d++)
                progressBar1.Value = d;

            Hide();

            new Form1().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If four forms in my application, so our requirement is third page should be load on second page's button click but progress bar should be run before third page load. It's not working over here, my third page loaded very slow., SO Please give me the solution.